# How to update 'title in jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: title, jquery-ui-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery ui dialog change title after load-callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171763/jquery-ui-dialog-change-title-after-load-callback)

I like to change the title from an UI Dialog after I have submitted a form in this UI Dialog. So in the callback-function after `load` I should suggest, but I've tried and googled without result.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The [`option`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-option) method will change a dialog's properties after the dialog is created.

Therefore, you can write

```js
$(whatever).dialog('option', 'title', 'New Title');
```

Comment: But how to OPEN AND CHANGE title? Hum... "open" is a action-method, "change title" is a set-value-method, so we can do a chain:  `$(whatever).dialog({title:"MyTitle"}).load('myContent.htm').dialog('open')` !

Comment: Worked like charm :) +1

Comment: @PeterKrauss, it worked for me too, you should elaborate an answer :)

Answer (score 6):

you can also use this, before open it

```js
$("#YourContainer").data('title.dialog', ' I am the new title');
```

Comment: does not work.. var d= $("#dialog"); d.data('title.dialog', ' I am the new title'); d.dialog("open");