# jquery dialog title undefined using global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have set a var in my code then made it global, but for some reason, dialog is showing it as 'undefined'. Can you not have var in title? Thanks

In .click event

```
box = $('#EB_custref').val();
```

Outside of function

```
var box;
```

In dialog options

```
title: 'Edit box' + ' ' + box,
```

Comment: you need to post more code...

Comment: @william. why have you downvoted me?

Comment: how do you know it was me? I did not downvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `title: 'Edit box' + ' ' + box` line gets run when you instantiate your dialog: I assume you're doing that on `$(document).ready`. At that point, your `box` variable is undefined.

When you set `box` on the `click` event it's too late - the title has already been set.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171763/jquery-ui-dialog-change-title-after-load-callback) for further info.

---

**EDIT**

Here's a demo of one solution for this:

**HTML**

```
<button data-title="Apple">OPEN 1</button>
<button data-title="Banana">OPEN 2</button>

<div id="MyDialog">
    Example Dialog Content
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var globalTitle = ''; // Your global variable

// Startup operations
$(function () {

    $('#MyDialog').hide();
    $('button').click(function () { 
                          openMyDialog($(this).data('title')) 
                      });
});

// Open the dialog using the global myTitle variable
function openMyDialog(customTitle)
{
    globalTitle = customTitle;
    $('#MyDialog').dialog({title : globalTitle});
}
```

Note the use of HTML5-style `data-` attributes, which rock, and are accessible in jQuery through the `.data()` function. Also note that I've used a global variable to show you that it's possible to use one. However there's no need for it - the best approach would be to pass `customTitle` straight into the `dialog()` call, i.e. `$('#MyDialog').dialog({title : customTitle});`

Comment: Thank you for that james. I was aware of hacking the css directly.

Comment: How do i then james based on your comment, make the box global from the click event? thanks

Comment: The `box` var *is* global, it's just that you used it to set the `title` property when it was undefined. Because `title` is just a string, it doesn't matter if you subsequently change the value of `box`. `title` will remain the same literal string i.e. 'Edit box undefined'. The best thing for you to do is run the dialog instantiation code on the click event.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that please james. Quite new to js & jquery. Thanks

Comment: James. Thank you. However, I am still getting errors. Here's the scenario. I need to capture this value which I do to populate the form: var custref = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(8) div").text(); $("#boxeditform").find("#EB_custref").attr({value: custref }); It is value I am trying to capture to make var for title. thanks

Comment: This populated the form with the correct data which can then be processed with the .click event

Comment: What I find confusing james, is that I can use 'box' in a beforeclose event in dialog but not in the title. title: 'Edit box',
            width: 470,
            beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
                if(flag==1){
                    flag=0;
                    jAlert("You have successfully edited\n\rBox: "+box+"\n\r"+
                           "Status: "+status+"\n\r"+
                           "Size: "+size+"\n\r", 'Box addittion successfull');
                }

Comment: Then pass `box` into the `openMyDialog` (or your equivalent) function. I think you need to spend more time learning javascript to get comfortable with these concepts. As I have already explained, `box` is undefined when you initially set `title`. It *is* defined by the time your call to `jAlert` runs. You need to understand the fact that your javascript runs in a lifecycle - function code executes when it is called. Anything outside a function gets executed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('#EB_custref').val())
```

Check that its returning value or not

and if possible post more code/