# jquery - change the title of a button

Tags: jquery, button

i have button set up like:

```
<button id="invOn2" style="float: left;">Item 2</button>
```

the button is inside a dialog, and i am trying to change the title of the button as the dialog is being opened:

```
$('#invOn2').button( "option", "label", "shwaf");
```

this isnt working, what is wrong?

---

the suggestions havent worked as of yet, im going to elaborate on the structure of what im doing:

//jquery setup

```
 $(function() {
      $('#invOnBox').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 300,
      });
      $('#invOnButton').click(function() {
            $('#invOn1 button').html('shwaf');
            $('#invOnBox').dialog('open');
            return false;
      });
    });
```

//the invDialog and inner button

```
 <div id="invOnBox" title="Inventory">
    <button id="invOn1" style="float: left;">Item 1</button>
    </div>
```

//the invOnButton

```
<button id="invOnButton" style="float: left;">Inventory</button>
```

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well 2 things:

This selector won't find any elements

```
$('#invOn1 button')
```

Since it tires to find a button element inside the element with id #inv0n1, so change it to only the ID selector.

```
$('#invOn1')
```

I would also do the changes on the dialog open event. This due to that my dialogs are often dynamic ones.

```
$('#invOnBox').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 300,
        open : function () {
            $('#invOn1').html('shwaf');
        }
  });
```

..fredrik

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`$('#invOn2 button').html('shwaf');`

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted.  using .text("shwaf") would be better but still...

Comment: I find that sometimes `.text()` doesnt work, so I use `.html()`