# jQuery change original-title text on click?

Tags: jquery, text, click

I have this html line:

```
<div class="hide-btn top tip-s" original-title="Close sidebar"></div>
```

And when a user clicks on it i want that the text change to 'Open Sidebar' how can i do this?

This is my JS:

```
$(".hide-btn").click(function(){
    if($("#left").css("width") == "0px"){
        $("#left").animate({width:"230px"}, 500);
        $("#right").animate({marginLeft:"250px"}, 500);
        $("#wrapper, #container").animate({backgroundPosition:"0 0"}, 500);
        $(".hide-btn.top, .hide-btn.center, .hide-btn.bottom").animate({left: "223px"}, 500, function() { $(window).trigger("resize");});
    }
    else{
        $("#left").animate({width:"0px"}, 500);
        $("#right").animate({marginLeft:"20px"}, 500);
        $("#wrapper, #container").animate({backgroundPosition:"-230px 0px"}, 500);
        $(".hide-btn.top, .hide-btn.center, .hide-btn.bottom").animate({left: "-7px"}, 500, function() { $(window).trigger("resize");});
    }
});
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an element's title attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery) ... this will help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change an attribute on an element using jQuery, you use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr). Within an event handler hooked up with jQuery, the original DOM element is available as `this`. To get a jQuery wrapper around it, use `$(this)`. E.g.:

```
$(this).attr("original-title", "new text");
```

---

Side note: The attribute `original-title` is invalid for `div` elements. Consider using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I like to do this one for that kind of thing :-)

```
var a = $(".hide-btn.top");
a.attr('original-title', a.attr('original-title').replace(/Close/, 'Open') );
```

May seem overcomplicated but I often change my mind about the exact labels afterwards and this saves me having to go back and adjust everything.