# jQuery Replace Page Title from User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the page title from a text area, when the 'Go' button is pressed with jQuery.  I have yet to be successful.  I have tryed replaceWith(), but that didn't work so I tried this:

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title
<script src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script src="go.js"></script>
<link id="si" rel="shortcut icon" media="all" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
<!-- This was for trying to change the icon (also unsuccessful) -->
<link id="i" rel="icon" media="all" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="title">Type the new title.>;/textarea>
<!-- Put the favicon switcher here -->
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
<br />
</body>
</html>`
```

go.js:

```
$(function go() {
    var title = document.getElementById('title').value();
    document.title = title;
});
```

Comment: Next time you can simply use four (4) spaces for code blocks and multiply (2+) spaces at the end of the line for linebreak.

Comment: How About using Google?
With a Simple Good Search this is What I found:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery

Comment: just remove $( and ); from go.js &try

Comment: I'm looking for  solution that can also work for updating the favicon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="updateTitle()" id="tinput">
        <script>
            var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
            title = title[0];

            var titleInput = document.getElementById('tinput');

            function updateTitle() {
                title.innerHTML = titleInput.value;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Oh, you are looking for jQuery solution. I'll just keep the answer, maybe somebody else will have use of it :)

Comment: Thanks!  This is useful, though a jQuery solution would be nice, so I could also use it to change the favicon.

Comment: No one else seems to be posting, and this way works the best (though a few of the others work too), so I am marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this go function:

```
function go() {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    $('title').text(title);
};
```

Comment: This does not change on clicking.

Comment: Sorry, edited it...the function was wrongly executed on document-ready

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $("button#go").click(function() {
     document.title = $("#title").val();
   });
});

<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
go = function () {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    alert(title);
    document.title = title;
}
```