# How to use jQuery variable into html

Tags: jquery

This is an example what i need to do.

jQuery:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var inputvalue = "field 1";
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div><input value="<!-- inputvalue here -->"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('input').val(inputvalue);`

Comment: the comment above will work for your specific case since you have only 1 input in your html. You should use ids for your input, in case you have multiple ones
$('#SomeInput').val(inputvalue);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var inputvalue = "field 1";
      $('#id1').val(inputvalue);
   });
</script>

<html>
<body>
<div><input id="id1" value=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about other attributes like size and other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery