# change anchor attribute with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="tile">

<a href="#" title="some other title"><img src="#">
     <div id="newTitle">
     <h1>I want the real title here</h1>
     <p>some useful paragraph</p>
     </div>
</a>

<a href="#" title="some other title"><img src="#">
     <div id="newTitle">
     <h1>Another title here</h1>
     <p>another useful paragraph</p>
     </div>
</a>

</div>
```

I want to change the anchor titles with the respective DIVs within that anchor using jquery

does anyone have a solution for this?

here's what I've tried:

```
 <script>
 var eachTile = $("#tile > a"),
 newTitle = eachTile.children("#newTile").text();

 eachTile.attr('title', newTitle);
 </script>
```

this script shows all texts in one line so all of them has the same text.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an element's title attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery)

Comment: edited with the code i've tried...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use like this
Inside every anchor, "newTitle" should be class, not ID, because you can not call same ID multiple times from multiple items, so use class instead of ID

**jQuery**

```
$('#tile a').each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).find('.newTitle').text();
    $(this).attr('title',txt);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tile">

<a href="#" title="some other title"><img src="#">
     <div class="newTitle">
     <h1>I want the real title here</h1>
     <p>some useful paragraph</p>
     </div>
</a>

<a href="#" title="some other title"><img src="#">
     <div class="newTitle">
     <h1>Another title here</h1>
     <p>another useful paragraph</p>
     </div>
</a>

<a href="#" title="some other title"><img src="#">
     <div class="newTitle">
     <h1>Another title here</h1>
     <p>another useful paragraph</p>
     </div>
</a>

<a href="#" title="some other title"><img src="#">
     <div class="newTitle">
     <h1>Another title here</h1>
     <p>another useful paragraph</p>
     </div>
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
function changeTitle(){
document.getElementsByName("add a name").title = "Set title";
}
```

To use with a function callable from event.

Comment: thanks...I was hoping I would be able to change it with the texts that is within the DIVs