# Is there a way to set a title for the div element's :before or :after?

Tags: css, title

```
<img src="..." title="Some title here">
```

Is the a way to do the same for the div:before or div:after via css?

Comment: you can do that by using jquery [reference][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery

Comment: Hi now you can try this crate a div and define background image and do this as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/3f5L6/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this..

```
document.getElementById('divId').title = 'title';
```

Comment: No, that sets the `title` attribute of the element which is already done in the markup.