# read a html checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, websocket

Not sure if this is the correct question but baiscally I have html form which has a checkbox.  i'm using websockets that need to pull that value with the javascript code.  But regardless of weather the box is checked or not, it shows the value of 'yes'.  How should I go about getting the coorect value to pull into python...?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>
<title>Flask-SocketIO Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        namespace = '/test'; // change to an empty string to use the global namespace

        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('my event', {data: 'Connected... Waiting for you...'});
        });


        socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
            $('#log').append('<br>' + msg.data);
        });


        $('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('my event', {data: $('#emit_data').val(), 
                                     checkbox: $('#checkbox').val() 
                                    }
         ); 
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flask-SocketIO Test</h1>
<h2>Send:</h2>
<form id="emit" method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type="text" name="emit_data" id="emit_data" placeholder="Message"><br>
    <input id="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
    <input type="submit" value="Echo"></div>
</form>
<h2>Receive:</h2>
<div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector `:checked` and test if the length of the selected elements is greater then 0:

```
$('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: $('#emit_data').val(), 
                                 checkbox: $('#checkbox:checked').length > 0 
                                }
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways but I prefer reading the `checked` property:

```
var isChecked = $('#checkbox').prop('checked');
```

This is another equivalent statement that reads a little nicer:

```
var isChecked = $('#checkbox').is(':checked');
```

The reason you are seeing it always checked is because `val()` is inspecting the `checked` attribute and not the `checked` *property*. Both of my examples should read from the *property* instead of the *attribute*. The *attribute* is reflective of the originally rendered markup and not the true current state of the control.

[More on properties vs. attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery/987974#987974).

Comment: got it, is there a central location for this kind of information?

Comment: There is a small section titled "Attributes vs. Properties" on the [jQuery API Documentation page for `prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). If you're going to put jQuery in your toolbox, I highly suggest reading through the *entire* API Documentation site. So there's that, and 12 years of web application development experience... :)