# replace text and attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

i just start to learn jquery so i know nothing. help me to change text and  attributes (title)

```
<li><a href="#" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a></li>

title="LinkedIn"    ==== title="instagram"
LinkedIn    === Instagram
```

thank you

Comment: what do you mean by `title`? `title` of document being displayed? if so use `document.title='LinkedIn';`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Your question can't be answered in its current state. We ask you to improve it first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an element's title attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987967/how-to-change-an-elements-title-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give your "a" an id, like so:

```
<li><a id="myAElement" href="#" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a></li>
```

Now to change the title, do:

```
$("#myAElement").attr("title","Instagram");
```

To change the text displayed, do:

```
$("#myAElement").html("Instagram");
```

Comment: thank you it works. title changed. now need to change  <a href="#" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a> to <a href="#" title="LinkedIn">Instagram</a>

Comment: $("#myAElement").html("Instagram");    should do the trick.