# Can an ICEFACES commandButton title attribute have style like bold text?

Tags: html, css, jsf, icefaces

Using ICEFACES, I need that a title attribute of a "commandButton" to have some of its characters bold.

I mean, having:

```
<ice:commandButton style="width:8%" rendered="true" title="Michael air Jordan" actionListener="#{someBean.write}" />
```

I would like that for example the word "air" in the title attribute would be bold. Michael Jordan not bold and air bold --> Michael **air** Jordan

I tried putting `<b>air</b>` inside the attribute title, but it does not work.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

I don't think it can be done with an HTML button. You cannot render HTML in the `value` or `title` attributes, so it cannot be done in an IceFaces button, which basically translates to an `<input type="submit"...>` tag.

But this question can help you achieve what you want: [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip (title attribute)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer, it was faaaast!!! But what I need to have "format" (bold) is the title, what we use to call the "hint" the yellow box that appears over the button when the mouse pointer stays on the button for a while. The text inside that yellow box is what I need to have format. That is what, in icefaces is set with the "title" attribute. I also have an image in the button. but it does not have any text, and it does not have to have it (ask my boss why :p)

Comment: My bad. I misread your question. In this case, you are trying to edit the tooltip. It is a standard attribute in many HTML elements. And no, it cannot be formatted either. But this question can help you achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip

Comment: Ouch, now it is my bad, I promisse I find a lot before posting, but I looked for "hint" and "title" I did not know it was called tooltip, so I did not find much. Thanks a lot, I quickly read the other post you send me to, I'll ask my boss if I should spend time trying that way or not... Thanks!!