# Render Html String in tooltip

Tags: asp.net, calendar, tooltip

I have a asp.net Calendar. On DayRender event of calendar I want to render html as tooltip.

```
e.Cell.ToolTip= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("add<BR>peek")
```

But its not working. How to render in browser as html.But it was rendering as

```
"asdsa&lt;BR&gt;peek"
```

Edit:
I tried like this in another way.

```
Label b = new Label();
b.Visible = false;
b.Text = "add<BR>peek";
e.Cell.Controls.Add(b);
```

Displaying fine. But I want to display label onhover the calendar date. How can I do this? Can any one help me. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not possible to put html in a tool tip, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip

Comment: oh..k.Thank you.I tried like this `label.Text="add<BR>peek"`. I have added it to `e.Cell.Controls.Add(label)`. How can i make visible onhover calendar date. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be with jQuery. You need to make the containing cell and the label identifiable to unobtrusive javascript by using css classes. Then you can create a function for when the cell is hovered over which will find the label and display it, then hide when the mouse moves away:

Append the following lines to the server side logic you have already:

```
b.CssClass = "js-tooltip";
e.Cell.CssClass = "js-tooltip-container";
```

Your html should then look like (you don't have to code this part, its the result of your code behind):

```
<td class="js-tooltip-container">
    <label class="js-tooltip" style="display:none;">add <br /> peek</label>
</td>
```

Then you need to add the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".js-tooltip-container").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".js-tooltip").show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".js-tooltip").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

The javascript makes use of the [jQuery hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). This is all boiler plate stuff so if you want something more robust and customisable I would consider using one of the plugins suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484144/1048369).

Comment: where should i add `<td class="js-tooltip">`

Comment: The `td` should get rendered as `class="js-tooltip-container"`. The `td` will be generated by your code behind. By setting the CssClass property on the cell with `e.Cell.CssClass = "js-tooltip-container";` you will get a table cell with the class attribute applied to it.

Comment: hey..thank you. i got it. its working. Can i make it as a ballon?