# AngularJS Display Tooltip Content of Array of Strings / With HTML

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug

**HTML (Jade):**

```
a(href='#', data-placement='right', title="{{ someArrayOfStrings }}" tooltip)
```

where `someArrayOfStrings` is declared given a value during initialization in my angular controller:

**Angular:**

```
var myController = function($scope) {
    $scope.initialize = function(someArrayOfStrings) {
        $scope.someArrayOfStrings = someArrayOfStrings;
    }
};

var tooltip = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).hover(function(){
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                $(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Currently, this would give my tooltip content such as the following:

```
["string1","string2","string3"]
```

which is ugly as hell and totally NOT what I want.

What I want displayed is something like this:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

---

I have searched around and it seems like there are quite a few approaches to this but so far, I have not managed to get it to work nicely, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/fu7a2/6/, http://jsfiddle.net/WR76R/ and [Render Html String in tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386504/render-html-string-in-tooltip).

Alternatively, I could perhaps use a concatenated string delimited by `<br/>` tags. This would require that my tooltips accept HTML tags, however. There seems to be an tooltip option available, i.e. `html: true`, but I can't get it to work.

Ideas / Help?

---

Demo fiddle @ [jsfiddle.net/zr89sq6L/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/zr89sq6L/10/)

Comment: Used in directive `.tooltip` - tooltip is `jquery`?

Comment: It's Angular; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666900/using-bootstrap-tooltip-with-angularjs, @StepanKasyanenko

Comment: Are you trying `$(element).tooltip({html: 'true', container: 'body'})`?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a `bootstrap` intended for `angular`? See this [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/getting-started).

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: I know of angular UI: https://angular-ui.github.io/, but after some consideration, decided not to use it, mainly because my project is not entirely in angular, and because it is a little too late to be switching now, :/.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/zr89sq6L/10/, @StepanKasyanenko Oddly, the tooltip works even without the directive; it doesn't work on my webapp without the directive though... (Or rather, it does, but it is just like the black thing you see in the fiddle, and not the nice red I changed it to in my CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/u511juwj/).

- First, create **directive** that create **tooltip** `$(element).tooltip({html: 'true'})`.
- Second, use `stringArray.join('<br>')` create string with **br**.

Example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.stringArray = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];

  })
  .directive('tooltip', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $(element).tooltip({
          html: 'true'
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <div ng-repeat="string in stringArray">
      {{ string }}
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-placement="right" title="{{ stringArray.join('<br>') }}" tooltip>tooltip</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works on the fiddle, but not on my webapp, :( My strings just look like this: `string1<br>string2<br>string3`. It is still not rendering the HTML.

Comment: I realized smth funny. The `.run` is making a weird tooltip div appear on the top left hand corner of my webapp and it says my page title (not "string1" etc.) Also, I have no idea when it appears and disappears. Looks very strange and random. It also changes the title on my browser tab, O_O. Any idea why?? My tooltips are inside body > container >  some rows and columns > panel body.

Comment: Hey, that worked! Strange! Cause I thought I tried this before but it didn't work :S Maybe I made a typo back then T_T Thank you so much! :) @Stepan  Kasyanenko

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set the title property like `title="{{ stringArray.join('\u000A') }}"`. Please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Noblemo/u9tt9xb2/

Comment: It works on the fiddle, but not on my webapp, :( My strings just look like they are delimited/joined by spaces rather than new lines, e.g. `string1 string2 string3`.

Comment: Fyi, I am using Firefox :/ but still it doesn't show as new lines.

Comment: Which is the version of firefox?

Comment: Could you please try \n or \x0A instead of \u000A?

Comment: I tried both and both don't work, :S @NOBLE M.O. Version 44.02 on Ubuntu 14.04.