# Change font size of <td> title attribute?

Tags: html, css

What's the simplest way to change the  title attribute font size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't : the `title` attributes are displayed in an system specific and non HTML way.

To tune how they look, you'll have to build and display your own divs on mouse hovering (or use an existing "bubble" library).

---

On request :

Here's a minimal "bubble" library, using jQuery :

```
$('[data-bubble]').hover(function(e){
  if (window.bubble) window.bubble.remove();
  bubble = $('<div>', {
    text: $(this).data('bubble'),
    css: {
      position:'fixed',
      top:e.pageY, left:e.pageX,
      background:'yellow'
    }
  }).appendTo(document.body);
}, function(){
  window.bubble.remove();
});
```

Usage :

```
<span data-bubble="some Text">HOVER THIS</span>
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/axinaz/2/)**

I'll let you do the syling you like. If you don't use jQuery, I let you port it to vanilla-js, I think you get the idea.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to tune my own divs (without "bubble" library) please.

Comment: @aF I edited my answer with a bubble code I just made for you.