# Custom IE8 tooltip for title="tooltip description"

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, tooltip

there is any possibility use css in order to style title="title description" on IE8? without use jQuery?
something like:

html

```
<a href="#" title="tooltip description">this must be a toltip</a>
```

css

```
 a[title]:hover{
        background: lime;
        border:1px solid #eaeaea;
        opacity: .6; 
        position: absolute;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip)

Comment: You can't style title attribute :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the title popup is managed by the browser. Its content isn't even interpreted as HTML and you can't style it.

If you want a styled popup, you have to generate it yourself using some javascript. In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027301/change-font-size-of-td-title-attribute) I show how you can do it simply (here with jQuery but you can adapt to vanilla js).

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/axinaz/2/)**