# HTML img tooltip with html expression

Tags: html, tooltip

I want to create tooltip in img which is html expression

Example:
`<img title="<b>My tooltip</b>" src="..."></img>`

But what I get is text `<b>My tooltip</b>` not processed html.

Is some way to do it?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I think, title attribute does not support markups inside. What you can do is create hidden divs which get displayed onMouseOver using some script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip)

Comment: Yes, you need to create a _custom_ tool-tip. You can't display html in a native tool-tip. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117073/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-div or http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Comment: my suggestion is use some javascript libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not possible to format the text in the tooltips with HTML. 
You'll have to use something like [jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) .