# increase size of title text on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want increase title tag size on mouse hover which is in anchor tag. so how can target to title.

```
<a href="#pop-up-form" rel="wp-video-lightbox" title="Nous contacter" class="a">kesar sisodiya</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip)

Answer (score 1):

The `title` text is handled by the browser and is not made available to us. You *could* make your own `title` text handler with JavaScript, but I don't think that's a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't increase the size of title property.

You can try using the tooltip provided by jQuery.
[jQuery Tooltip example](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: Its not an answer but it usefull, so i can't approve as an answer but i'm giving you +1

Comment: @kesarsisodiya, “You can’t” is an answer, the correct answer. There are several workarounds, “CSS tooltips” being most popular.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a div that displayed when you hover over your text.

```
<div class="custom_title_tag">This is the title</div>
```

then style it with css

```
a:hover .custom_title_tag {
    background:black;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

The first answer was pretty straightforward though.  But you could just position it relative to the link title you want to show.

Comment: Thats good trick but i can't use it, coz its not possible to use this in my code  :(

Comment: You could use absolute positioning as well, but it's worth more headache than it's worth more than likely.  I'd use Javascript if I were you.  Or just live with the way it is haha.

Answer (score 0):

check this, hope it helps you

```
    a {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }


    a:hover {
      color: green;
      position: relative;
    }


    a[title]:hover:after {
      content: attr(title);
      padding: 4px 8px;
      color: #000;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      z-index: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background:#ccc;

    }
```

Comment: Its totaly like hover, it is not a looks like title.