# resize tooltip with qTip

Tags: jquery, css, qtip

As per some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute) SO answers  I'm using [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/guides#style) to format my tooltips as this is impossible in CSS.

My goal is to make the tooltip larger.

The basic example for qTip is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/10286/): essentially,

```
$('a[title]').qtip()
```

. What do I need to add to this to increase the font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a css class for `.qtip`

```
.qtip{
    font-size: 18px;   
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/10289/)**