# How to change checkbox title style?

Tags: html, css

This is example of my code

```
 <style>
        label {
            font-style: italic;
            color: red;
            font-size: 40px;
        }
  </style>

        <tr id="required">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="fantasia"><label title="this is fantasia">Fantasy</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="dokument"><label title="this is dokument">Dokument</label>
              </td>
        </tr>
```

I tryed to found solution of Shobhit Srivastava link. No result.

Comment: title [type="text"][title]:hover:before {
    font-style: italic;
    color:red;
    font-size: 40px;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip (title attribute)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute)