# How do you change an element's name attribute's CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the pop-up of an element using CSS, yet it doesn't work.

```css
name {
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button title="name">Test</button>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use the attribute selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```css
button[title="name"] {
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button title="name">Test</button>
```

Comment: I want to edit the popup, not the button itself.

Comment: @SenpaiSaitama what popup? You didn't include any of that in your post.

Comment: The popup which comes when you hover over something... The title attribute

Comment: @SenpaiSaitama oh, you can't style that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the tooltip style cannot be changed in any browser.

I'd suggest you implementing your own with CSS (add a hidden `span` or some other element with the tooltip and show it on `button:hover`) or JS (nicer as you could set a delay before is shown).

Comment: I want to edit the pop-up, not the button itself

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear. Your snippet doesn't show any popup. Please, post more code or a working example and I'll update my answer.

Comment: The popup that comes after you hover on something... The title attribute

Comment: Oh, you meant the tooltip. No, you can't edit its style.