# How to display some text bold from title attribute in <a href

Tags: html, href, title

I want to display some text of title in bold in  tag
I tried the below code but it didn't work for me.

```
<a href="http://google.com" title="This is <b>Bold Title</b>">Link</a>
```

Is there any way to display some text of title in bold?

Comment: You should add a class to the <a> tag, and then style it using CSS 'font-weight: bold;

Comment: @Rubenxfd Thank you for suggesting but can you please give more brief that how to do this?

Comment: It's not possible to style the title directly, but there are alternatives, like a custom tooltip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip (title attribute)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute)

Comment: You could always use Unicode characters, (such as these https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=BOLD), assuming your site uses UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize title attribute but you can add some tooltip as advice above.

Some cool tooltip : https://tympanus.net/Development/TooltipStylesInspiration/