# Why can't I change the font size of the title in image anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the colorbox plugin for my gallery from:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/.

I want to change the font-size of the title in the anchor tag, so I tried adding a font-size into the properties of #cboxtitle. However, it the size of the font is still the same. I also tried doing an inline styling on the anchor tag but to no avail. Is there a way to change the size of the font of the title for the anchor tag?

Below is the html code I am using:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="section">
    <p><a class="group4" href="Images/event1.jpg" title="Gallery 1 image"><img src="Images/event1.JPG" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px;"/></a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="section">
    <p><a class="group4"  href="Images/event2.jpg" title="Gallery 2 image"><img src="Images/event2.JPG" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px;"/></a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="section">
    <p><a class="group4"  href="Images/event3.jpg" title="Gallery 3 image."><img src="Images/event3.JPG" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px;"/></a></p>
 </div>
```

CSS for the colorbox:

```css
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
#cboxWrapper {max-width:none;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;  font-size: 40px !important;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0; padding:0; margin:0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;}

#cboxOverlay{background:#fff; opacity: 0.9; filter: alpha(opacity = 90);}
#colorbox{outline:0;}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -50px;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -75px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px -25px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:25px; background:url(images/border2.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:25px; background:url(images/border2.png) repeat-y -25px 0;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:20px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#999;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:100px; color:#999;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#fff url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 5px 5px;}
```

What I am having trouble with: Increasing the font size of "Gallery 1 image".

[Gallery Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJwFu.jpg)

Comment: So many things are wrong with this code that I must assume you didn't post it all. 1- #cboxtitle refers to an id, in the html it's a class so it should be .cboxtitle 2- There is no text in the html, only images so no css can change the font size if there is no written text. 3- id="section" is used 3 times; an ID is unique, otherwise you should use a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute

Comment: It is not possible to change the size of the title tooltip.  If you want to do that, you will need to use a js plugin to make the tooltip

Comment: So the font-size of the attributes in "title" in the anchor tag(E.g. Gallery 1 image" cannot be modified? Thank you for pointing out the semantics of the section part. But the code runs fine for section(didn't apply much styling for section).

Comment: It depends what happens to that title, if it is being rendered out as an actual title in the gallery, then you would need to inspect that element and change the font size of that, if it is the popup tooltip that you are talking about, then you cannot change the size of that

Comment: It is not a popup tooltip. I just want to increase the size of "Gallery 1 Image" through CSS.

Comment: The text you enter inside the title tag is displayed in a popup when a user takes their mouse over to an image, which is why we are all refering to a popup tooltip. Perhaps the lightbox you are using recuperates the title attribute and does something else with it, but that is not in the code you posted; we can only go with what you give us. If you leave it as is you can only style it with jquery, but that is not the way I would personally do it. If you want to style it with css, you'll need to make it standard html text, for example by puting it in a div and styling it with hover and display.

Answer (score 0):

From Your code, `cboxTitle` is **`class` not `id`**,

change,

```
#cboxTitle{margin:0;  font-size: 40px !important;}
```

to,

```
.cboxTitle{margin:0;  font-size: 40px !important;}
```

**PS:**

Changing the style of a `tooltip` is not possible by default in html,  you can use Jquery for it as mentioned in one comment

[Here is Jquery tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

[For tool-tip custom styling](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style)

Comment: Hi sir, I didn't realize I forgotten to remove the selector because I was testing. But I tried your method and it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this method

Answer (score 0):

This selector would apply to an ID

```
#cboxTitle{margin:0;  font-size: 40px !important;}
```

But you use classes in your HTML, so it needs to be

```
.cboxTitle{margin:0;  font-size: 40px !important;}
```

Comment: Hi sir, I didn't realize I forgotten to remove the selector because I was testing. But I tried your method and it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm - now (after you edited your question / code) it's even less clear which element you want to have a smaller font-size (?)

Comment: I am using the default colorbox css provided by http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/. The CSS by default runs fine on the HTML. But now I want to change the font-size of the "title" selector.